# How do I put text over the picture?

Tags: html, css

I have this [Website](http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=10)

**HTML:**

```css
.lista_sus li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 9px 5px 0;
  background-color: #041067;
}
.lista_sus li p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista_sus">

  <li>
    <img src="./wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/1.png" alt="Smiley face" height="250" width="250">

    <p class="hide">
      <div class="title">Zorica L. Codoban
        <br>avocat
        <br>
      </div>

      - Avocat din anul 1997
      <br>- domenii de specialitate: drept civil, drept comercial, drept succesoral, drept imobiliar, dreptul muncii, drept administrativ, dreptul familiei;
      <br>- limbi vorbite: franceza.
    </p>
  </li>
```

I want to position text over the image ... I did some testing we have found here in the forum but not working.

How can i solve this problem?
Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems to work for me, a z-index value maybe, all the ffour coordonates to zero ? to fill entire li ... what do you expect as result ?

Comment: This markup is currently invalid, since you're placing a block element within an inline-block element (that nested div is invalid syntax where it currently is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working example](http://codepen.io/palashbasak/pen/NPEJax)

```css
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul li {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
  }
  ul li img {
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  ul li p {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg" alt="">
    <p>
      Avocat din anul 1997
      <br>domenii de specialitate: drept civil, drept comercial, drept succesoral, drept imobiliar, dreptul muncii, drept administrativ, dreptul familiei;
      <br>limbi vorbite: franceza.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create HTML  `background Image`

Or change structure for HTML code and use `float` for this.

Answer (score 1):

## Option1: Use background Image

You could set the image in the background of a div, and have text within the image:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
```

```html
<div>This is some text</div>
```

---

## Option2: Use Positioning

You could use a wrapper div (`position: relative`), and position the text and image accordingly (`position: absolute`):

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.text,
.wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.text {
  z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="text">This is some text</div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
  .picture {
    background: url("http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2012/09/07/13037/big_thumb_97f1fdc4221e259ac57c475977627b9d.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="picture">TEXT HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you make a div with position relative. And in it you have a img, and a text element that is absolute positioned where you wan't it.

Comment: Yes a background image would be the simple way of course :) no-brainer, but I think you need to use imgs for a reason.